# Show input text with different names Checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this scenario.

I'm doing a sell system, i have the sales Indexed, and marked as paid or not.

So, i list all the sales from a specific client, and showed it, with php, i put some checkbox to say what sales u want to mark as paid. So, i wanna show a textbox on the right side of this checkbox and check if the total paid is the same as indexed, if mark as paid, and show a box to put the date, else shows a textbox to enter the amount paid, and strip it of the total bill.

But i dont know how to do this using javascript/jquery.

```
<form action="carregaPagamento.php">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Produto</td>
            <td>Quantidade</td>
            <td>Valor</td>
            <td>Ação</td>
        </tr>
        <?php if(isset($_POST['acao']) && $_POST['acao'] == 'enviar'){
            $cliente = $_POST['cliente'];

            $select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vendas WHERE metodo = 'aprazo' AND cliente = '$cliente'");
            while($res = mysql_fetch_array($select)){

                echo '<tr>
                        <td>'.$res['produto'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$res['quantidade'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$res['valor'].'</td>
                        <td class="action">
<input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="paid">Paid
                        </td>
                </tr>
                ';
            }
        }
        ?>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `checkbox` why don't you use `buttons` with `modals` ?

Check an example of modal:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Bootstrap is a *Framework* of CSS+JavaScript ( that uses jQuery )

Then when the user clicks the button, a modal shows asking if he wants to confirm the payment and may show a calendar ( there are multiples implementations of calendars within jQuery ). And sending the input through AJAX

Also, i would recommend you to do *input sanitization*

Sorry if my answer is not what you expected, i didn't understood your question at all :P

Boa sorte!

Comment: how can i pass the bill id to the modal box?

Comment: Suppose each _bill_ is a row in your table. That table **must** have an `id` column, right ? You just have to pass the `id` to the modal `input` and then receive in the PHP script the _input id_ via `$_POST`. By the way, don't forget to sanitize

Comment: For example, changing the input value to `$row['billId']`

Comment: sorry for late reply, i tried using buttons with modals, it works actually, but when i have a lot of bills, and the customer paid a total of like, 3 bills, instead of putting the total paid of each bill, why not select some bills, and open a modal? i'm not having idea how to do it

Comment: `{form}{checkbox1}{checkbox2}{checkbox3}{formbutton}` then `{formbutton}` calls a moddal that considers all the checkbox that are toogled inside the current form